# How to pass current-prefix-arg to this-command

Tags: search, replace, emacs, key-bindings

I want to reuse `current-prefix-arg` when calling `this-command`. I can imagine ways of capturing its value and passing it to modified functions. But, this doesn't seem like a great solution. How can I reuse it (eg. push it back onto a sort of call stack, or whatever emacs uses)?

The example is a simple function to increment/decrement numbers in region I was just writing where I want to temporarily bind <kbd>i</kbd> to increment or decrement if it was called with prefix. Can I do this without adding another argument to the function, but just using the original prefix?

```
(defun my-toggle-increment-numbers (start end)
  "Simple function to increment numbers in region. Decrement with prefix."
  (interactive "r")
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (goto-char start)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\([[:digit:]]+\\)" end 'move)
      (replace-match (number-to-string
                      (+ (if current-prefix-arg -1 1)
                         (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
                     nil nil nil 1))
    ;; what is good way to reused the current-prefix-argument value when
    ;; calling this-command?
    (set-transient-map
     (let ((km (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key km "i" this-command)
       km)
     t)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(defun my-toggle-increment-numbers (start end &optional decrement)
  "Simple function to increment numbers in region. Decrement with prefix."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (setq start  (copy-marker start)
          end    (copy-marker end))
    (goto-char start)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\([-]?[[:digit:]]+\\)" end 'move)
      (replace-match (number-to-string (+ (if decrement -1 1)
                                          (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
                     nil nil nil 1))
    (set-transient-map
     (let ((km  (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key km "i" `(lambda ()
                             (interactive)
                             (my-toggle-increment-numbers ',start ',end ',decrement)))
       km)
     t)))
```

1. You forgot to include the minus sign preceding your `[[:digit:]]`.
2. You need to either use lexical binding or construct a command that binds the current values of `start`, `end` and `current-prefix-arg` (or `decrement` - see next).
3. It's a bit simpler if you use an argument instead of `current-prefix-arg`.

   (You ask if you can just use `current-prefix-arg` instead of adding an arg for it. Yes. In that case, let-bind `current-prefix-arg` in the constructed command that gets invoked for subsequent calls.)
4. Since replacement can change the number of digits in a numeral (e.g. from `9` to `10`, you need to use a marker instead of the number value of `end` in subsequent calls.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi : Pushing onto unread-command-events may (or may not) work, but if the user then invokes some other command, who knows what effect your prefix argument would have?! I'm pretty sure you don't want to be doing anything like that.

Comment: The previous prefix-arg value is available as `last-prefix-arg` however, so `(let ((current-prefix-arg last-prefix-arg)) ...)` is a thing you could do. I've not tested this, but you might try `(let ((current-prefix-arg last-prefix-arg)) (call-interactively last-command))`

Comment: @phils Thanks, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is to create a command which calls `this-command` passing it the prefix arg:

```
;; This relies on -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(defun my-toggle-increment-numbers (start end)
  [...]
  (set-transient-map
   (let ((km (make-sparse-keymap))
         (tc this-command)
         (cpa current-prefix-arg))
     (define-key km "i"
       (lambda () (interactive)
         (let ((current-prefix-arg cpa))
           (call-interactively tc))))
     km)
   t)))
```

It's probably more verbose than what you were imagining, but I think it's the closest there is to what you're asking.  A simpler way to get almost the same result could be:

```
(defun my-toggle-increment-numbers (start end)
  [...]
  (setq prefix-arg current-prefix-arg)
  (set-transient-map
   (let ((km (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key km "i" this-command)
     km)
   t)))
```

Comment: @jenesaisquoi: Indeed, my first example was missing a "petit je ne sais quoi", which I just added now.

Comment: thanks again, I ended up with your second example with some modifications suggested by @Drew